# Add jquery to angular 2 wepack project (Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack

I'm using the angular-cli .net core starter. Now I'm adding my own css + javascript and getting following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

I already tried:

```
npm install jquery
```

+

```
import $ from 'jquery'; => in app component
```

How do you configure jquery with webpack / angular2 ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not using a dedicated Bootstrap + Angular integration that doesn't require jQuery nor Bootstrap's JS at all? https://ng-bootstrap.github.io

Answer (score 1):

Install the type definitions:

```
npm install @types/jquery
```

Answer (score 0):

steps

1. `npm install jquery — save`
2. Add `"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]` to angular-cli.json file
3. Import it into the component : `import * as $ from 'jquery';`
4. Example:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("button").click(function(){ 
        ...
      } 
   });
   ```